# How to implement an ion-refresher with $http fired from a route resolve

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Ionic project and I'm acquiring data from an REST API through $http service. I do this throughout a resolve inside a route that brings the promise from a service, and inject into a controller.  My doRefresh function is within that controller, however, the resolve is within the route, thats may doubt.

My **route** is here:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl as vm',
    resolve: {
      weather: function(MyService) {
         return MyService.getData();
     }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

My **service** is here

```
.factory('MyService', function($http) {
   function getData() {
       return $http.get('http://something.api?format=json')
              .then(function(res) {
                 return res.data;
              });
   }

   return {
     getData: getData()
   };
});
```

And, finally, here is my **controller**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function(weather, $ionicLoading) {

   var vm = this;
   vm.weather = weather;

   vm.doRefresh = function() {
       // how can I resolve the promise here?? It is right? Is this the correct architecture?
   }

});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `weather` should return a promise. So, you can do like this in your controller:

```
vm.weather.then(function(){
   ...
})
```